# Serialize to XML in diffgram format without DataSet

Tags: xml, serialization

I need to pass serialize objects to XML in diffgram format as this is required by a legacy webserver however it is not possible to use the DataSet object to do this.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Specify the language/technology. I assumed this is C#/.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create a desired [diffgram structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff420770(v=sql.105).aspx), for example, using LINQ to XML.

To generate a Diffgram (taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172088(v=vs.110).aspx)):

- Generate a list of root objects (that is, objects without any parent).
- For each object and its descendants in the list, write out the current version of all properties in the first Diffgram section.
- For each child object in the parent object, write out the original version of all propertis, if any, in the `<before>` section of the Diffgram.
- For object that have errors, write the error content in the `<errors>` section of the Diffgram.

Also check this [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172629.aspx) of useful examples.